# ¿Se puede hacer NavLink en el evento onClick de un Button?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, material-ui

Soy bastante nuevo en el uso de React y estoy desarrollado una plataforma web con Material UI. Estaba aprendiendo a enrutar mi página web con la `react-route-dom` y con el uso de `BrowserRouter`, `Switch` y `Route`.

Quiero mantener ciertos componentes como el Header en la página web y que, según el botón que clique, cambien el resto de componentes de la página de manera que pueda cambiar entre la página principal y una dos Headers, el que está por defecto en todas las rutas y otro añadido que es el mismo:

```
class Router extends Component {

render() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Header/>

            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ListOfLessons}/>
                    <Route exact path="/g" component={Header}/>
                    <Route component={Error}/>
                    {/*<Route path="/segundo" component={Slider} />*/}
                </Switch>
            </main>

            <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
}
export default Router;
```

Entonces quería hacer que presionando un Button situado en el Header, me fuera por ejemplo del path "/" a "/g", por ejemplo, pero no se la sintaxis para hacerlo. He probado lo sigüiente sin éxito:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={<NavLink to="/g" />}>¡Quiero saber más!</Button>
```

He visto que cuando el link es una palabra, no un boton, entonces si que funciona. Por ejemplo:

```
<li>
<NavLink to = "/g">¡Quiero saber más!</NavLink>
</li>
```

Comment: Intenta envolver la etiqueta button con NavLink `<NavLink to="/g"><button>Quiero saber mas</button></NavLink>`, puede que eso funcione, saludos.

Comment: Funciono! Solo que tuve que añadir un estilo para que no apareciera la barra horizontal azul: style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con `react-router-dom` puedes darle al usuario dos maneras de navegar, una es mediante una simple etiqueta `Link` que viene con `react-router-dom` y la otra manera es mediante lógica, a continuación unos ejemplos.

1. Esta es una forma de enrutar utilizando las etiquetas

---

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Header extends Document {
   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <Link to="/home">
           ir a la home
         </Link>
         <Link to="/dashboard">
           ir al tablero
         </Link>
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

2. Otra manera de poder redirigir a los usuarios es utilizando `history` que nos provee el Componente `Route` para manejar mediante logica, de esta manera

---

```
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/g" component={Header}/> //presta atencion al componente Header
   </Switch>
```

el componente `Header` que agregas como componente, recibe una propiedad del enrutador, si muestras por consola los `props` podras observar una propiedad `history`, puedes utilizar esta propiedad de la siguiente manera

```
export default class Header extends Document {

   GoHome(){
     this.props.history.push("/home")
   }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
          <button onCkick={GoHome}>
            ir a la home
          </button>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

espero que hallas entendido, suerte.

Comment: Muy interesante! He probado lo que dices en la parte 2 pero me salta un error: "React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook f
unction  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks". Lo he declarado tal y como pusiste en el ejemplo, dentro de class y antes de render

Comment: ok esto es debido a un error mio, `useHistory` es un hook de react y como tal no se puede utilizar en una clase de react, editare la respuesta con otro ejemplo

Comment: Funcionó, gracias!

Comment: no olvides votar la respuesta, saludos.!!

Comment: Buen ejemplo de respuesta me funciono para lo que estaba realizando.